# Removing height and width from images with a caption

Tags: images, responsive, captions, twitter-bootstrap

I am using WordPress with Twitter Bootstrap 3 and have an issue when it comes to images with captions.

Images with captions are given a height and width attribute which stops them from being responsive.

I tried the following code below but this only works for images without captions:

```
function change_uploaded_image_html( $html ) {
    // Removes height and width attribute from images when they
    // are uploaded.

    $classes = 'img-responsive';

    if ( preg_match( '/<img.*? class=".*?" \/>/', $html ) ) {

        $html = preg_replace( '/(<img.*? class=".*?)(".*?\/>)/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $html );
    }
    else {
        $html = preg_replace( '/(<img.*?)\/>/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" \/>', $html );
    }


$html = preg_replace( '/(height|width)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
return $html;
```

}

I then tried another method from another post on this forum which sets the width attribute to nothing but I did not get any success as the width and height attribute on the image remains:

```
function my_img_caption_shortcode_filter( $val, $attr, $content=null ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'    => '',
        'align' => '',
        'width' => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr ) );

    if ( 1 > ( int ) $width || empty( $caption ) )
        return $val;

    $capid = '';
    if ( $id ) {
        $id = esc_attr( $id );
        $capid = 'id="figcaption_'. $id . '" ';
        $id = 'id="' . $id . '" aria-labelledby="figcaption_' . $id . '" ';
    }

    return '<figure ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" >'
    . do_shortcode( $content ) . '<figcaption ' . $capid 
    . 'class="wp-caption-text">' . $caption . '</figcaption></figure>';
}
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode_filter',10 ,3 );
```

I am looking for a way to do this with PHP and WP's in-built filters and I think I am close to the answer but do not know in which direction to go exactly.

Many Thanks,
nav

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possibility, it alters the image markup when you select an image to add to your content in the editor

```
  add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_img_attribute', 10, 8 );

   function remove_img_attribute( $html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt ) 
    {
       $imagetpl = '<figure>
            <a href="%s" title="%s"><img src="%s" alt="%s" class="img-responsive %s" /></a>
            %s
       </figure>';
       $figcaption = (!empty($caption)) ? sprintf('<figcaption>%s</figcaption>',$caption):null;
       $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id,'large');
       return sprintf($imagetpl,$image[0],$title,$image[0],$alt,$align,$figcaption);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the below solution. It was found [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/responsively-removing-width-and-height-attributes-in-images-on-wordpress/)

```
add_shortcode( 'wp_caption', 'fixed_img_caption_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'caption', 'fixed_img_caption_shortcode' );

function fixed_img_caption_shortcode($attr, $content = null) {
if ( ! isset( $attr['caption'] ) ) {
if ( preg_match( '#((?:<a [^>]+>\s*)?<img [^>]+>(?:\s*</a>)?)(.*)#is', $content, $matches ) ) {
     $content = $matches[1];
     $attr['caption'] = trim( $matches[2] );
     }
 }
 $output = apply_filters( 'img_caption_shortcode', '', $attr, $content );
     if ( $output != '' )
     return $output;
 extract( shortcode_atts(array(
 'id'      => '',
 'align'   => 'alignnone',
 'width'   => '',
 'caption' => ''
 ), $attr));
 if ( 1 > (int) $width || empty($caption) )
 return $content;
 if ( $id ) $id = 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ';
 return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" >' 
 . do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $caption . '</p></div>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code, if you want the image original size and not the cropped version why don't you use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` instead?

In Reply to your comment:->

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );
function my_img_caption_shortcode( $empty, $attr, $content ){
    $attr = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'      => '',
        'align'   => 'alignnone',
        'width'   => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr );
    if ( $attr['id'] ) {
        $attr['id'] = 'id="' . esc_attr( $attr['id'] ) . '" ';
    }
     $classes = 'img-responsive';

    if ( preg_match( '//', $content) ) {

        $content= preg_replace( '/()/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $content);
    }
    else {
        $content= preg_replace( '/(/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" \/>', $content);
    }


$content= preg_replace( '/(height|width)="\d*"\s/', "", $content);
 return ''
    . do_shortcode( $content ) . '' . $caption . '';}
```

this worked for me, it it doesn't for you, you may want to look at other hooks that are forcing the width on your images